How do debug pairing of matter/thread devices with HomeKit (Apple TV 4K 3rd gen)?
I am trying to connect 2 Eve motion blinds (thread based devices) to an existing HomeKit setup. The home hub is an Apple TV 4K (3rd) gen.
When I scan the barcode of a blind, it is recognised. When I select Add to HomeKit on my iOS device, it starts with Connecting..., then it changes to Configuring....
This takes a couple of minutes, and the an error shows up with the message

Pairing the device failed.

I have a Unifi home network with 2 networks and wifi, one for work and one for the rest.
Can anyone recommend me some tools on how to debug this? Is it possible to get some logs from the IOs device to get some indicator what's wrong?

Do you have a Mac? Do you have Xcode?

Not sure if that can apply in your case, but the usual way to debug stuff on iOS devices is to:

Have a Mac
Install Xcode (takes quite a bit of space)
Connect the device to the Mac (Lightning/USB). It will take some time to "prepare" the device
You can then view system logs either in Xcode or via the standard macOS "Console" application (which is not a terminal but a log viewer)

It's actually possible that viewing the logs in the Console is possible without Xcode, but I have no idea if that's actually the case.
This works well for iPhones (and iPads), I suppose it should work the same on Apple TV.
The logs can be very verbose, but Console allows you to filter the logs, it's a matter of finding the right search string (probably "HomeKit" or "matter" or similar things).
Of course, logs can be very clear and explicit or they can be just a lot of unintelligible data. It may or may not be helpful. I've never looked at logs for HomeKit/matter so I can't tell you if they can actually be useful to you.

Thanks, that got me some debug logs that seem to indicate there's a connection issue (Timeout) somewhere in the mDNS lookups.
com.csa.matter error 20:31:25.525794+0200 homed Error on commissioning step 'ThreadNetworkEnable': 'src/app/CommandSender.cpp:328: CHIP Error 0x00000032: Timeout'
com.csa.matter error 20:32:10.559478+0200 homed OperationalSessionSetup[1:00000000E86C7FE6]: operational discovery failed: src/lib/address_resolve/AddressResolve_DefaultImpl.cpp:120: CHIP Error 0x00000032: Timeout
so the issue might have to do with mDNS settings in the network stack.

CHIP Error 0x00000032 is kinda googleable. (CHIP = connected Home over IP, which is the non-branded name for the Matter standard.)
